# Correct way to "split" rows in pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

TL;DR : in pandas, what is the best way to split a row into several rows based on a given criteria, with some changes to the values based on the split?

---

I have the following dataframe:

```
                         description  value  country
0      pen number 29143 for client X    100   France
1                      pen num 99523     90       UK
2            pen 58123 and pen 88421    250    Spain
3             pen 10594 for Mr Smith    145    Italy
4  pen number 19534, 94212 and 55645    285  Germany
```

I know that pen IDs are the only 5-digit codes in that field. I want to "split" the rows with multiple IDs and allocate value equally, keeping other fields identical:

```
      id  value  country
0  29143    100   France
1  99523     90       UK
2  58123    125    Spain
3  88421    125    Spain
4  10594    145    Italy
5  19534     95  Germany
6  94212     95  Germany
7  55645     95  Germany
```

I have a working method for this, but it creates multiple dicts and doesn't look at all like the best and most efficient way to do this. It looks like this:

(This uses basic re to identify the 5-digit IDs in strings)

First, I create the "id" column and fill for all single-ID fields.

```
df['id'] = df['description'].apply(lambda x: re.findall('\d'*5,x)[0] if len(set(re.findall('\d'*5,x))) == 1 else None)
```

Then I create a dictionary of index : list of IDs for descriptions with multiple IDs

```
multiple_id_dict = {}
for i in df.index:
    ids = list(set(re.findall('\d'*5, df.loc[i, 'description'])))
    if len(ids) > 1:
        multiple_id_dict[i] = ids
```

After that, for each index, I create a dictionary of that row in my dataframe, and turn every value into a list of five times itself (keeping other data). I then assign correct IDs and values to the dict, turn it into a dataframe and append it to the original frame. Finally, I remove the original (now split) row.

```
for i in multiple_id_dict:
    id_list = multiple_id_dict[i]
    row_dict = df.loc[i].to_dict()
    row_dict_sep = {x: [row_dict[x]]*len(id_list) for x in row_dict}
    row_dict_sep['id'] = [x for x in id_list]
    row_dict_sep['value'] = [row_dict['value']/len(id_list)]*len(id_list)
    df = df.append(pd.DataFrame(row_dict_sep), sort=True)
    df = df.drop(i)
```

This seems very convoluted. Is there a simpler or vectorial way of "splitting" rows, with some sort of an "agg" to determine treatment of each value in the row?

PS: code to copy/paste to get example dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'description': ['pen number 29143 for client X','pen num 99523','pen 58123 and pen 88421','pen 10594 for Mr Smith','pen number 19534, 94212 and 55645'],'value': [100, 90, 250, 145, 285], 'country':['France','UK','Spain','Italy','Germany']})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`Series.str.extractall`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extractall.html) with regex `(\d{5})` for five digits for one column `DataFrame`, [`DataFrame.join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) to original and divide count created by [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) per groups with same size like origianl data:

```
df1 = df.pop('description').str.extractall(r'(\d{5})').reset_index(level=1, drop=True)
print (df1)
       0
0  29143
1  99523
2  58123
2  88421
3  10594
4  19534
4  94212
4  55645

df = df1.rename(columns={0:'id'}).join(df)
df['value'] /= df.groupby(level=0)['value'].transform('size')
df = df.reset_index(drop=True)
print (df)
      id  value  country
0  29143  100.0   France
1  99523   90.0       UK
2  58123  125.0    Spain
3  88421  125.0    Spain
4  10594  145.0    Italy
5  19534   95.0  Germany
6  94212   95.0  Germany
7  55645   95.0  Germany
```